# How to fix my Python code to look for occurrences across multiple URLs and not just one

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, first time doing anything in Python, and any coding language for that matter.

I want to count how many lawyers in a certain company that attended different schools.

What I've got so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get("https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
solo_body = soup.body
body = solo_body.text.lower()
stockholmcount = (body.count("stockholms uni"))
lundcount = (body.count("lunds uni"))
uppsalacount = (body.count("uppsalas uni"))
goteborgcount = (body.count("göteborgs uni"))
orebrocount = (body.count("örebros uni"))
karlstadcount = (body.count("karlstads uni"))

urls = ['https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/hanne-aarsheim/', 'https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/sarmad-abdul-nabi/']
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    solo_body = soup.body
    body = solo_body.text.lower()
    stockholmcountadd = stockholmcount+(body.count("stockholms uni"))
    lundcountadd = lundcount+(body.count("lunds uni"))
    uppsalacountadd = uppsalacount+(body.count("uppsalas uni"))
    goteborgcountadd = goteborgcount+(body.count("göteborgs uni"))
    orebrocountadd = orebrocount+(body.count("örebros uni"))
    karlstadcountadd = karlstadcount+(body.count("karlstads uni"))
print("Stockholm: " + str(stockholmcountadd))
print("Lund: " + str(lundcountadd))
print("Uppsala: " + str(uppsalacountadd))
print("Göteborg: " + str(goteborgcountadd))
print("Örebro: " + str(orebrocountadd))
print("Karlstad: " + str(karlstadcountadd))
```

What I've noticed though, is that the output only looks at one of the URLs, and if I add a "break", it changes what URL that the script acts upon, but it never does both.

Gladly appreciate any help!

Edited for formatting purposes.

Comment: What exactly is the problem

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar No matter how many URLs I put, depending on if I put a "break" or not, it ONLY returns matches for the first or last URL, never a combined sum.

Comment: *lundcountadd*, for example, will have the sum of its initial value and the count of "lunds uni" from the last url in the list

Comment: @Stuart Yes, what I'd like is for each URL to be checked and counted, so if all students (in this case, all URLs) did go to Lunds uni, the output would be "2" for lundcountadd.

Comment: your code is super hard to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider building a dictionary keyed on the search phrases then build the whole thing into a loop like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/', 'https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/hanne-aarsheim/', 'https://www.mannheimerswartling.se/medarbetare/sarmad-abdul-nabi/']

phrases = ["stockholms uni", "lunds uni", "uppsalas uni", "göteborgs uni", "örebros uni", "karlstads uni"]

results = {}

for url in urls:
    (r := requests.get(url)).raise_for_status()
    body = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml').body.text.lower()
    for phrase in phrases:
        results[phrase] = results.get(phrase, 0) + body.count(phrase)

print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
{'stockholms uni': 1, 'lunds uni': 1, 'uppsalas uni': 0, 'göteborgs uni': 0, 'örebros uni': 0, 'karlstads uni': 0}
```

**Note:**

You'll need to do some work on the output but you should get the point